# Dial-by-name in Froyo?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, phone-app

I recently installed 2.2.2 (official update from my provider) on my Virgin Mobile Samsung Intercept. Among other changes, this ROM uses the stock UI instead of the Touch Wiz interface from Samsung. One thing I'm having a hard time putting up with is the lack of a call-by-name feature. In 2.1, I used to be able to call "Bob" by dialing 26 (B O) and then selecting Bob from the list. Is there a way to make 2.2 do this? If it was a Touch Wiz thing, is there an app I can install to bring this functionality back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternate Dialing app like [Dialer One](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.DialerOne) or [GoContacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact). What you're looking for is a T9 dialer.

Comment: I guess that's the way I'm going to have to go. Thanks for the suggestion.